# how to store database values in radio buttons those radio buttons values retrieve from another table in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i have two tables in my database one is notifications another one is notification_expire_types..in notification form i created expire types as radio buttons..how to store those radio button expire_types values in notifications form in codeigniter..please help me

```
<div class="col-md-12 not_margin">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label txt_view">Expires By</label>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="ui-radio ui-radio-pink">
        <label class="ui-radio-inline">
         <input type="radio" checked name="expire_type_id"> 
         <span>1 Day</span>
        </label>
        <label class="ui-radio-inline">
         <input type="radio" name="expire_type_id">
         <span>1 Week</span>
        </label>
        <label class="ui-radio-inline">
         <input type="radio" name="expire_type_id" > 
         <span>15 Days</span>
        </label>
        <label class="ui-radio-inline">
         <input type="radio" name="expire_type_id" > 
         <span>1 Month</span>
        </label>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Access your `expire_type_id` using `$this->input->post('expire_type_id')` in your controller if you are posting your form & store it to the database

Comment: i already store in my controller..i have dynamic values in my database

Comment: <label class="col-md-3 control-label txt_view">Expires By</label>
             <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="ui-radio ui-radio-pink">
           <label class="ui-radio-inline">
             <input type="radio" name="expire_type_id"> 
             <?php foreach($notificationtype as $row) { ?>
             <option value="<?php echo $row->expire_type_id?>"><?php echo $row->expire_type?></option>
              <?php } ?> 
             
            </label>

Comment: i tried like  this but when i write like this values are displayed but radio buttons are not appeared

Comment: first add your radio button value like <input type="radio" checked name="expire_type_id" value="1day">
and check when your form submit print post array like
$this->input->post('expire_type_id');

Answer (score 0):

```
// Pass boolean value to third param
// Example:
$radio_is_checked = $this->input->post('expire_type_id') == '1 Day';

echo form_radio('expire_type_id', 'F', $radio_is_checked, 'id=expire_type_id');
```

Something like above please build your radio buttons

Comment: where should i add this one

Comment: in the view replacing `<input type="radio" checked name="expire_type_id"> `

Comment: @Bira radia button value is set your button like <input type="radio" checked name="expire_type_id" value="1day"> that

Comment: then you can see your post array and insert in DB

Comment: Please refer the documentation carefully there is many ways to do this. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#set_radio

Comment: Please see below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618792/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-gender-radio-button-male-female-with-codeigniter

Comment: @Bira you can check validation in controller ?

Comment: set a rules there.. `$this->form_validation->set_rules('field' => 'expire_type_id', 'label' => 'Expire type', 'rules' => 'required');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124177/discussion-between-hardik-paghdar-and-bira).