# Asking user to select gender

Tags: php, codeigniter

Sorry I'm not a good programming.

I own website made by Codeigniter, Can you Guidance  me what to Search to show two radio buttons For gender `"Male","Female"` in welcome page after user signup ?
flash data is good? or pop up message?

Comment: hello I dont use codeigniter but maybe this question help you :   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618792/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-gender-radio-button-male-female-with-codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

Use like this in welcome page

```html
<input type='radio' name='gender' value='male'>Male
<input type='radio' name='gender' value='female'>Female
```

Comment: How to post this to database? This is the question
I made Warning instead of this till find how to post this.

Comment: write code after snippet option selected in answer section